# Function that Receives and Returns one of two Types

Tags: java, templates, generics

I'm migrating C++ code into Java and ran into the following problem.
I have four classes (after moving to Java): `ABuilt, ABuilder, BBuilt, BBuilder`.

```
class ABuilt implements A {
  private BBuilt b;

  public A(BBuilt b) {this.b = b;}
  @Override
  public BBuilt getB() {return b;}
}

class ABuilder implements A, Builder<ABuilt> {
  private BBuilder b;

  @Override
  public getB() {return b;}
  public setB(BBuilder b) {this.b = b;}
  @Override
  public ABuilt build() {return new ABuilt(b.build();}
}

class BBuilt implements B {
  int data;

  public BBuilt(int data) {this.data = data;}
  @Override
  int getData() {return data;}
}

class BBuilder implements B, Builder<BBuilt> {
  int data;

  @Override
  public BBuilt build() {return new BBuilt(data);} 
  public BBuilder(int data) {this.data = data;}
  @Override
  int getData() {return data;}
  void setData(int data) {this.data = data;}
}
```

I have a function that gets an `A` and returns its `B`. This is pretty simple:

```
B getB(A a) {return a.getB();} // This works fine.
```

The problem is the following scenario:

```
void setData(ABuilder a, int data) {
  BBuilder b = (BBuilder) getB(a);
  b.setData(data);
}
```

I would like to avoid the cast. I could solve this by writing two functions `getBBuilder(ABuilder a), getBBuilt(ABuilt a)`. This is not good both because I either repeat the code in the two functions or unnecessarily build `a` and because I have to change all usages in the code base from `getB` to either of `getBBuilder` or `gtBBuilt` (there are a lot of them and I don't know if I can script it away). Is there any way to define `getB` in such a way that it will return type `BBuilder` if `a` is of type `ABuilder` and `BBuilt` if `a` is of type `ABuilt`? In C++ this is easy by `typedef`ing in `ABuilder` and in `ABuilt` a type `BType` which is defined as `BBuilder` and `BBuilt` respectively. Then defining `getB` as follows:

```
template <class AType>
AType::BType getB(AType a) {return a.getB();}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. Does `B` have the `setData` method ? You said you want to get either `BBuilder` or `BBuilt` but `setData` is only available in `BBuilder`. Please clarify your goal.

Comment: No Built types are immutable. The design is that you construct objects using builders and then serialize them into their built form. I want my libraries to be able to work with either built classes or builders but to return the correct type so as to not have to downcast the return type always.